# how to Skip the scanning from anti virus for creating Mysql service using inno setup installer

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

Questions:  how to Skip the scanning from anti virus for creating Mysql service using inno setup installer???

I have inno setup installer for creating Mysql Service in Windows services but when already antivirus installed Facing Problems for creating mysql service. How can i skip the scanning from anti virus and windows firewall.

below is Code.

```
#define MyAppName "NEW_MYSQL"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "NEW_MYSQL"

#define MyAppExeName "NEW_MYSQL.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{36057E04-FDC0-4FE0-AB77-23F18955F60C}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={code:GetProgramFiles}\{#MyAppName}
DisableDirPage=yes
DefaultGroupName=NEW_MYSQL
LicenseFile=C:\Users\hyva\Desktop\NEW_MYSQL\NEW_MYSQL_license.txt
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir=C:\Users\hyva\Desktop\NEW_MYSQL\Setupfiles
OutputBaseFilename=setup_New_e

Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\hyva\Desktop\NEW_MYSQL\NEW_MYSQL\*"; DestDir: "{pf32}\NEW_MYSQL"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files


[Run]
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "stop MySQL" ; Flags: runhidden
Filename: {pf32}\NEW_MYSQL\bin\MySQLInstanceConfig.exe; Parameters:"-i -q ""-l{pf32}\NEW_MYSQL\mysql_install_log.txt"" ""-nMySQL Server 5.5"" ""-p{pf32}\NEW_MYSQL\"" -v5.5.23 ""-t{pf32}\NEW_MYSQL\my-template.ini"" ""-c{pf32}\NEW_MYSQL\my.ini"" ServerType=SERVER DatabaseType=MIXED Port=3319 StrictMode=yes ConnectionCount=15 Charset=utf8 ServiceName=MySQL-HA AddBinToPath=yes RootPassword=myserver"; WorkingDir: {pf32}\NEW_MYSQL\bin\; StatusMsg: Configuring MySQL services; Description: Configuring MySQL Service; Flags: runhidden 
Filename: net.exe;Parameters: start MySQL;StatusMsg: Starting MySQL Server;Flags: runhidden

[UninstallRun]

Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "stop MySQL" ; Flags: runhidden
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Parameters: "delete MySQL" ; Flags: runhidden
```

Comment: Can you please comment on your last question !?

Comment: anti virus and windows firewall should not scan when creating service.

Comment: I mean to comment [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49008805/1322642)